# Javascript: Does <audio>.captureStream() work without play()?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, html5-audio

In the browser, I want to capture the stream of an audio tag that has an .mp3 as source, then send it live via WebRTC to the server. I don't want to hear it via the speakers.

Is it possible to call audioElement.play() without having speaker output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that one can mute the audio element and still capture the stream:

`audioElement.muted = true;
var stream = audioElement.captureStream();`

Comment: This no longer seems to work as of Chrome 86. The resulting stream only has audio when the audio element is unmuted.

Answer (score 7):

`new Audio()` returns an [`HTMLAudioElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) that connects to your browser's default audio output device. You can verify this in the dev console by running:

```js
> new Audio().sinkId
<- ""
```

where the empty string output specifies the [user agent default `sinkId`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/sinkId).

A flexible way of connecting the output of an `HTMLAudioElement` instance to non-default sink (for example, if you don't want to hear it through the speakers but just want to send it to another destination like a [WebRTC peer connection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection)), is to use the global [`AudioContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext) object to [create a new `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamDestination). Then you can grab the [`MediaElementAudioSourceNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaElementAudioSourceNode) from the `Audio` object holding your mp3 file via `audioContext.createMediaElementSource(mp3Audio)`, and connect that to your new audio destination node. Then, when you run `mp3Audio.play()`, it will stream only to the destination node, and not the default (speaker) audio output.

Full example:

```js
// Set up the audio node source and destination...
const mp3FilePath = 'testAudioSample.mp3'
const mp3Audio = new Audio(mp3FilePath)
const audioContext = new AudioContext()
const mp3AudioSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(mp3Audio)
const mp3AudioDestination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination()
mp3AudioSource.connect(mp3AudioDestination)

// Connect the destination track to whatever you want,
// e.g. another audio node, or an RTCPeerConnection.
const mp3AudioTrack = mp3AudioDestination.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection()
pc.addTrack(track)

// Prepare the `Audio` instance playback however you'd like.
// For example, loop it:
mp3Audio.loop = true

// Start streaming the mp3 audio to the new destination sink!
await mp3Audio.play()
```